# Devolver consulta con XPath en JAVA

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb

Estoy un poco perdido y no entiendo como obtener mediante una consulta con XPath un valor especifico de un XML. La idea es crear un método "buscador" que le pase por parámetro la consulta, me devuelve el resultado y lo muestre por pantalla pero no puedo hacer que funcione ya que tengo un error en el for...

Por ejemplo, para obtener las notas(los 3 elementos) de Maria Gonzalez y mostrar a que modulo pertenece, como podría hacer?. No logro ver la forma mas eficiente de obtener estos datos, se me ocurre que seleccionando los nodos hermanos de , alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo? Gracias

XML

```
     <modulos>
         <modulo m="M01"> 
             <alumno>
                  <nombre>Maria Gonzalez</nombre>
                     <nota1>5.00</nota1>
                     <nota2>3.00</nota2>
                     <nota3>7.00</nota3>
             </alumno>
             <alumno>
                  <nombre>Pedro Rogers</nombre>
                     <nota1>1.00</nota1>
                     <nota2>2.00</nota2>
                     <nota3>5.00</nota3>
             </alumno>
        </modulo>
     </modulos>
```

---

```
        public String ConsultaXpath(String txtconsulta){

      
        String salida="";
          try {
         exp = xpath.compile(txtconsulta);
         Object result=  exp.evaluate(XMLDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
         NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) result;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName());   //---> no funciona
        }
        return salida;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    return "Error:" + ex.toString();
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenas te paso mi cacho codigo correspondiente a tu bucle for de consultaXpath():
...

```
NodeList listanodos = (NodeList) result;
```

...
a Partir de for

```
for (int i = 0; i < listanodos.getLength(); i++) {
                if (listanodos.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    datos_nodo = procesarLibro(listanodos.item(i));

                    salida = salida + "\n" + "Publicado en: " + datos_nodo[0];
                    salida = salida + "\n" + "El tituo del libro es: " + datos_nodo[1];
                    salida = salida + "\n" + "El autor del Libro es: " + datos_nodo[2] + "\n";
                    salida = salida + "******************************************" + "\n";
                    salida = salida + "******************************************" + "\n";

                }
```

y el metodo procesar libro donde accedo a los nodos de cada entidad xml y su contenido transformado en elementos de una array es :

```
private String[] procesarLibro(Node node) {
    String datosDelLibro[] = new String[3];
    Node temporal = null;
    int contador = 1;

    datosDelLibro[0] = node.getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();
    NodeList ListaDeNodos = node.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < ListaDeNodos.getLength(); i++) {
        temporal = ListaDeNodos.item(i);
        if (temporal.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            datosDelLibro[contador] = temporal.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            contador++;
        }
    }

    return datosDelLibro;
}
```

espero que te sirve y logras adaptarlo a tus necesidades